# How to force A2DP sink when wireless bluetooth headset is connected?

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth

I have Debian 9 Stretch installed in my pc,and when I want to hear some music i can't hear it well.I discovered in audio settings that the A2DP profile was there but nothing happens when I select it.There's a way to force the A2DP connection when connected the headset to the pc.I already paired it btw.

Help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

I am using a SoundBuds Curve headset in Debian 9, 
and have had the same problem, I was
unable to switch from the HSP/HFP profile to the A2DP profile.

What fixed the issue for me, was editing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

First, add the following lines under the [General] tag (copied from audio.conf):

```
# Automatically connect both A2DP and HFP/HSP profiles for incoming
# connections. Some headsets that support both profiles will only connect the
# other one automatically so the default setting of true is usually a good
# idea.
AutoConnect=true
```

Next enable support for multiple profiles, which can be found a few lines below in main.conf:

```
# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
MultiProfile = multiple
```

Comment: Last, restart Bluetooth service: `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

Comment: Did the trick for me with my Sony WH-1000XM2 on Debian 9

Comment: (sorry I forgot to log in when I edited your post so the modification will be requested as anonymous user)

Comment: After a long time of trying to fix this problem this was it. Thanks! Working flawlessly

Comment: After several weeks of use I can say it works BUT the problem is still that I have to restart the bluetooth service everytime before to connect my headset...

Comment: multiple profiles helps, just remember to change the profile in the sound settings

Comment: setting `MultiProfile = multiple` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` solved the problem for me in kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 here and solution not working. I cant switch from internal laptop microphone to headphones microphone

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me on Manjaro with my Sony WH-1000XM4

Comment: This worked well for me on ubuntu 20.04.1 using my sony WF-1000XM3

Comment: And.. it broke again. Pretty annoying how flaky this is

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having trouble with the soundbuds curve and my MBP running MacOS Mojave. It does connect fine, but has trouble switching back from "headset" mode/HSP|HFP to "music" mode/A2DP. I do run several virtualbox machines via vagrant for my development tasks. I only mention that because I previously used an app called oversight that basically sat between your camera & mic devices and OS so it would alert you if something tried to access them. I noticed starting debian VM's would trigger the Mic which may have played into my particular problem. I did run across this article, maybe there are some parallels for Debian?

> Other configuration issues may also disable AptX audio. As Darko.Audio
>   explains, on a Mac, if you’re using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi, if you have more
>   than two Bluetooth devices connected to a desktop, or if you have more
>   than one connected to a laptop, macOS drops down to lower-quality SBC
>   audio over the Bluetooth Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)
>   connection. That’s according to Apple.

...

> Technically, when you’re just using the headphones as a sound output 
>   device, they’re using the A2DP Bluetooth profile, and ideally using
>   AptX for maximum sound quality. When you need the microphone, they’ll
>   use the headset profile or hands-free profile (HSP or HFP). This
>   allows for both recording via the microphone and playback via the
>   headphones, but the headphone sound quality is terrible when using HSP
>   or HFP.

Ref: [why bluetooth headsets are terrible on windows pcs](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/)